# How to train machine learning to perform operations and give output?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

How can I train a system that is trained on input with processed output and predict the output on a new dataset. For example:

```
Training:
Inputs 1,3 Output = 4
Inputs 3,3 Output = 6
... ( thousands of addition examples)

Testing:
Input 5,6 Output = ?? 

The Output should be 11.
```

What framework, algorithm should i use? Can I do it with tensorflow? Is this possible with machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204756/training-a-neural-network-to-add). Don't look at the accepted answer, but one with most votes (by Ark-kun). In general, multilayer perceptron with one or two (in case of nonlinear functions) is your way to go. Just remember NOT to add any regularisation to the network, as you don't have any noise.